# select text from ajax response and show in input field when user click on item

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

> user type london record fetch from data base and show below the input field

```
<input type="text" id="inputSuccess" name="name" onkeyup="autosearch(this.value)" > //user type london
```

> when user click on london than london add in input field but it cannot set in input field what jquery script require to select the value from p tag and show in input field

```
<script>
function autosearch(name){
   //get data from database
   $.ajax({
       url:"ajax.php",
       type:'post',
       data: {name: name},
       success:function(result){
           $('.result').html(result);
       }
   });
}
</script>
```

**ajax.php**

```
<div style="border: 1px solid #ccc;width:100%;" >
   <a href="javascript:void(0)">
</div>
<div>
  <p><?php echo $data['cityName']; ?> </p> //london show here 
</div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Replace `$data['cityName'];` To : `$_POST['name'];`

Comment: I can barely understand what you are asking for. If you want to get text from `p` tag and set it as value of `input` use jQuery like this: `$("input#inputSuccess").val($("p").text());`

Comment: `user type london record fetch from data base`-> where you fetch record?

Comment: @AlivetoDie $data i am using while loop

Comment: if there is any image gallery site where  i put my code screent shot ??

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek you are close to my answer but p text come in a div

Comment: Then set an `id` for `p` tag: `<p id="result"></p>` and then use: `$("input#inputSuccess").val($("p#result").text());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your question then Here is an example to let you clear how to add text in the input. Please checkout below:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="inputSuccess" name="name" onkeyup="autosearch(this.value)" >

<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-val="textToShow" onclick="addTextInInput($(this).data('val'))">
  <div>
    <p>asd </p> 
  </div>
</a>
```

**JS:**

```
function addTextInInput(txt){
 //get data from database
   $("#inputSuccess").val(txt)
 }
```

Replace the `textToShow` in `data-val` with your `PHP` code and try it. Also, find working example here https://jsbin.com/witilohinu/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Please give your feedback in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure its you want. But this i understand from your code. if its wrong say me. I will help you fix this.
Add the class for your `<input>`    and set it Ajax result.

```
 <input type="text" id="inputSuccess" name="name" class='result'

       onkeyup="autosearch(this.value)" > //user type london


   <script>

   function autosearch(name){
 //get data from database
   $.ajax({
     url:"ajax.php",
    type:'post',
    data:{name:name},
    success:function(result){
      $('.result').html(result);
     }
  });
 }

</script>
```

You not need this Field.

```
<p><?php echo $data['cityName']; ?> </p> //london show here 
</div>
```

Comment: i think i want to edit my question so everyone understand my problem more clearly

Comment: <div style="width:80%;">
   <p><?php echo $data['cityName']; ?></p>
  </div>